# Method of a instance runs twice when called

Tags: python, object, python-3.x, methods

When I import a class to a different file, intance it and call one of it's methods, it runs twice

The class itself is:

```
class DBAuth(object):
    def __init__(self, driver=None, username=None, password=None,
                 host='localhost', port=None, database=None):
        self.driver = driver
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.database = database

    def test_method(self):
        teststr = "database is '{0}' and your user is '{1}'".format(
                self.database, self.username)
        return teststr
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
from lbauth.model import DBAuth

dbauth = DBAuth(
    driver = 'postgresql',
    username = 'user',
    password = 'passwd',
    host = 'localhost',
    port = '5432',
    database = 'dbname'
)

print(dbauth.test_method())
```

which returns:

```
>database is 'dbname' and your user is 'user'
>database is 'dbname' and your user is 'user'
```

Why does it behave like this and what would be the correct way to call this method properly?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this; there is *nothing* in the code you posted that would cause it to print twice.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think this is not the entire code - there has to be another call to `test_method()` somewhere but I don't have a magic crystal ball, do you?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've comment the whole code and left only this part to make sure, there isn't

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo: this could also be caused by a custom `print()` function, or by a custom `sys.stdout`.

Comment: @Rickin: does `print('anything else')` print twice? What does `print(repr(dbauth.test_method()))` print?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm using default python3.4 from the extra repository on ArchLinux

Comment: @MartijnPieters Your test does execute 'anything else' twice, and also, I just found out that this only happens when I import my class to another file, If I create the class and instance it on the same file, it behaves as expected

Comment: @Rickin: then your `print()` function has been altered. What does `print(print.__module__)` give you?

Comment: >builtins, I found out the problem, will post it as answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem.
Turns out I was using `__init__.py` to import and test scripts, which is a bad practice.